# Question about indexing characters of strings

Tags: string, go

Below is the program I created to understand how indexing of string characters work in Go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    vendor1 := "Cisco"
    fmt.Println(vendor1[0])  
    fmt.Println(vendor1[1:4]) 
    fmt.Println(vendor1[1:])  
    fmt.Println(vendor1[:])
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Golang\VARIABLE> go run .\variable.go
67
isc
isco
Cisco
```

What puzzled me is that Println(vendor1[0]) returns the number '67' instead of 'C', why is that so? Why it is different from Println(vendor1[1:4]) , Println(vendor1[1:]) and Println(vendor1[:]) which all return the desired characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Index expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) are not the same thing as [slice expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions), don't conflate them.

Indexing, as opposed to slicing, returns a `byte` which is a type alias of `uint8`, and `Println` simply prints out the unsigned integer.

Slicing returns a string, which is why `Println` outputs a text.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point. I figured out that I need to use string() to convert the byte to string after indexing.

Answer (score 1):

To print the value at index 0 use `fmt.Printf("%c\n", vendor1[0])` instead of `fmt.Println(vendor1[0])`,for the other three values you can use `%s` with `fmt.Printf()` since they are string.I modified your code as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    vendor1 := "Cisco"

    fmt.Printf("%c\n", vendor1[0])

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", vendor1[1:4])
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", vendor1[1:])
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", vendor1[:])

}
```

Output:

```
C
isc
isco
Cisco
```